# Change Windows Activation/License back to a trial

Tags: windows-7, license, windows-activation

I need to convert a Window 7 installation on a VM (which is licensed and activated) back to a trial.

What are the steps to do this?

**REASON for this (since one of the comments has asked):** Need to give a VM with a custom solution on it to a 3rd Party. I need to remove our Microsoft Windows License before giving it to them.

Comment: Because the Trial has a 120 day limit, I do not believe this can be done absent wiping the system and starting over.

Perhaps explaining why you need to revert to the trial will help us provide more creative solutions.

Comment: You could in theory just switch it to a generic license key

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: @music2myear I have added an explanation. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: `slmgr -upk` is what you want.

Comment: Good question. Can the downvoters clarify why they voted against this question?

Comment: @music2myear The votes seem subjective to me. I think that voters are thinking, "Why are you doing this?" as opposed to being not useful or unclear. This is why I prefer close votes (or recommend closure flags) and moderator flags as opposed to downvotes.

Comment: Please add comments if additional clarity is required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot vouch for these as I'm not willing to de-activate my copy of Windows. I just got these from a posting by username MarkJones1112 at this link ( http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/deactivate-windows-7-professional/4b808cc0-bf17-4528-a959-fdde6189b167 ). They should be run as an administrator.

1. To uninstall the product key, supposedly this works:

   > slmgr.vbs /upk
2. To reset the trial period, supposedly this works:

   > slmgr.vbs /rearm

Comment: Why was this downvoted? slmgr /upk is likely the correct answer.

Comment: Doing `slmgr /?` in a Win 7 command prompt says `Uninstall product key` for `/upk` and `Reset the licensing status of the machine` for `/rearm`.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to sysprep the system once you've got it running properly and before sending it off to the client. Sysprepping will allow you to require certain things of the client before the system actually runs correctly, including requiring they enter license information.

However, if you're not familiar with it, sysprep can take some getting used to and a good deal of trial and error.

Comment: This is new to me. I'll try on a copy of the VM and see. Thank you!

Comment: Last time I did serious work with sysprep was when I was doing migrations from Windows 95/98 to XP. It was pretty cool back then, and I know it's only become more powerful these days. If you're planning on deploying a solution like you're using now in the future on a repeated basis, getting to know sysprep may end up paying off dividends. It's a bit much for a single install/one-off project. But for repeated use in packaging and deploying products, it's pretty good.